# How to get data from mysql db which saved as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multiple-columns

I want to get the data from my mysql db , but one column is saved data as an array ... 
How can i get the values separately . Please advice...

This is how Data saved in db for the dropdown values

```
{"value":["Authority ","Boards"],"order":["1","2"]}
```

mysql query

```
SELECT a.select FROM sltdb_cddir_fields a WHERE a.categories_id=81
```

What i want is to get Authrity and Boards as two data values instead of this array ...

Please advice

```
 $searchg=$_GET["term"];
// $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sltdb_cddir_content where title like '%".$searchg."%'AND categories_id=81 order by title ASC ");
$query=mysql_query ("SELECT a.select FROM sltdb_cddir_fields a WHERE  a.select like '%".$searchg."%'  a.categories_value_id=19 ");
$json=array();
    while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $display["title"],
                    'label'=>$display["title"]
                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: after  you get data use unserialize to convert into array

Comment: @Karthick Kumar Ganesh : i wrote a query to get data but its output the same as which saved in array . you ask me to  unserialize the query results is it ?

Comment: why you are converting this to json array ?

Comment: @Karthick Kumar Ganesh : im using this for my jquery autocomplete and this json array is passed as source url

Answer (score 1):

The data format stored is in JSON format. Hence, you could obtain the data and parse them using the function `json_decode()`;
For instance:

```
    $data = '{"value":["Authority ","Boards"],"order":["1","2"]}';
    $objJSON = json_decode($data);
    $values = $objJSON->value;  //contains "Authority ","Boards"
    $orders = $objJSON->order; //contains "1","2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli offers several result types, mysqli_fetch_all() for instance returns an associative array.  If you want the data formatted in a non standard way, chances are you'll need to loop through it and build your data structures yourself.

```
$json = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json[$row['order']] = $row['value'];
}

return json_encode($json);
```

In JavaScript:

```
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
    html += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
});
```

Comment: i want this to on my json encode code, i have update my question as well , how to use this for that code . please advice

Comment: You should make an associative array, json_encode will convert that to a javascript object, then you can use $.each() from jquery to iterate through your object.

Comment: im using this for jquery autocomplete jQuery(function(){
                     jQuery("#searchp").autocomplete({  , how can i put $.each, pls advice

Comment: you please check this kindly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163466/how-to-filter-autocomplete-results-in-text-boxes

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode to change array to string like this

```
while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> implode(",", $display["title"]),
                    'label'=>implode(",", $display["title"])
                        );
    }
```

or even you can use [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead of implode

Comment: :can you please check this kidly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163466/how-to-filter-autocomplete-results-in-text-boxes

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Use the FIND_IN_SET function:**

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, t.ids) > 0
```