# How to filter autocomplete results in text boxes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have created autocomplete ajax search for a web site which auto complete organization names and addresses seperatly, 
but i want it to validate , when someone search organization name,  address text should give auto complete results only for
matching search organization name.

can anyone please advice me

organization address ajax :

```
$addresso=$_GET["term"];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sltdb_cddir_content where fulladdress like '%".$addresso."%' AND categories_id=80  order by fulladdress ASC ");
$json=array();
while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$json[]=array(
'value'=> $display["fulladdress"],
 'label'=>$display["fulladdress"]
 );
 }
```

**organization name ajax**

```
 $searcho=$_GET["term"];
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sltdb_cddir_content where title like '%".$searcho."%'AND categories_id=80  ");
 $json=array();
 while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $json[]=array(
 'label'=> $display['title'],
 'value' => $display['title'],
  );
  }
```

autocomplete jquery :

```
  jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery(function(){
              jQuery("#addresso").autocomplete({
                  source:'<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_jomdirectory_search/tmpl/gov-address.php'; ?>',

                  minLength:1
              });
          });

          jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery(function(){
              jQuery("#searcho").autocomplete({
                  source:'<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_jomdirectory_search/tmpl/gov.php'; ?>',

                  minLength:1
              });
          });
```

form :

```
<input id="searchc" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" name="search" "></input>
```

NOTE

what i exactly want is , when someone select a value from organization name text box, address text box should load the auto complete resuls which related to that organizatoin name. please advice

Answer (score 0):

**For organization name**

```
$searcho=$_GET["term"];
$seachArray = explode(',',$searcho);
$q='';
foreach($seachArray  as $term){
  $q .=" title like '%".trim($searcho)."%'  or ";
}  

$q =substr($q,0 ,-3);
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sltdb_cddir_content where ($q) AND categories_id=80  ");
 $json=array();
 while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $json[]=array(
    'label'=> $display['title'],
    'value' => $display['title'],
    );
  }
```

Edited after your comment

```
$searcho=$_GET["term"];
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sltdb_cddir_content where title like '%".$searcho."%'AND categories_id=80  ");
 $json=array();
 while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $json[]=array(
   'label'=> $display['title'],
   'value' => $display['title'],
   'address' =>$display['fulladdress'],
   );
  }
```

This will include address into your result. Now you have to work in your js as given below.

```
jQuery("#searcho").autocomplete({
                  source:'<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_jomdirectory_search/tmpl/gov.php'; ?>',
                      minLength:1
select: function (event, ui) {
    var address = ui.item.address;
    jQuery("#addresso").val(address);
  }
});
```

Ref -- [Jquery autocomplete on select event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722891/jquery-autocomplete-on-select-event)

Comment: what i exactly want is , when someone select a value from organization name text box, address text box should load the auto complete resuls which related to that organizatoin name. please advice

Comment: this is what i want, when some one type sometihn on first text box and select a value from autocomplete results, text boxx two address also shoud auto filter with respect to first text box value , please follow the url http://awesomescreenshot.com/0be2g4i0b1