# how to find a specific part from joomla url?

Tags: php, url, module, joomla3.2

This is url of my joomla site , i want to find whether the url contain alias= if its contain i need to hide header from that page

```
index.php?option=com_jomdirectory&view=item&id=18&alias=government1&categories_id=108&Itemid=110
```

so far i have tried putting this code on my index.php file , but it only search menu item id

```
<?php /** Getting the Menu ID of Menu was clicked by user **/
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$id = $menu -> getActive() -> id;

/** Getting the Title of the Menu by using id. **/
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT title FROM sltdb_menu WHERE id = $id";
$db -> setQuery($query);
$rows = $db -> loadObjectList();
$itemrow = $rows[0];
$title = $itemrow -> title;

$url = JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=' . $id);
if ($id >= 111 && $id <= 130) {
    echo "<style>#pageheading{ display: none;}</style><div > </div>";
}else {

    echo "";
}
?>
```

Please explain how to find whether the **alias=** is included to url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check input against to the specific part.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
if ($app->input->get('alias'))
{
    echo 'I am included!';
    // Do what you need here
}
```

Comment: glad to hear it helps!

Comment: :can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163466/how-to-filter-autocomplete-results-in-text-boxes/22179451?noredirect=1#comment33666162_22179451